# Passing apex:pageBlock title to Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have to pass the title of my apex:page block into my Controller. I could not find a way to do it. Any idea?

My code should look like that:

```
public PageReference saveFF() {       

 RecordType rt;
    if*(title == 'Motor')*
        rt = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Motor' And sObjectType = 'Fact_Finder__c'];

    FF.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;

insert (this.FF);    
return new PageReference('/' + recordId);    
  }
```

### Updates

```
 public string CurrentPageName {get;set;} 

 public PageReference saveFF() 
 { 

    RecordType rt; 
    if(pageName == 'HomeForm') 
        rt = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Home_Contents' And sObjectType = 'Fact_Finder__c']; 
        FF.RecordTypeId = rt.Id; 
    insert this.FF); 
    return new PageReference('/' + recordId); 
}
```

In the VF Page:

```
 <apex:commandButton action="{!saveFF}" value="Submit"styleClass="buttonsubmit" reRender="block" > 
 <apex:param name="p" value="{!$CurrentPage.Name}" assignTo="{!CurrentPageName}" />
```

Comment: I guess you have mutiple pageblock and you want to identify from which pageblock save method get called correct ? you may have multiple save buttons ?

Comment: Only one page block and one save button. But several VF pages on the same controller.

Comment: Then why you need pageblock title ? is it dynamic ?

Comment: No. I need the String to set my record type. As I said I have several VF pages on the Controller and depending on which VF page is saved it needs to have a different record type. I did not find another way than to pick the page name to set the record type. I also need this value to set other fields value in my controller.

Comment: SO basically.. you need to identify the current page. you can do it simply assign current page name to variable

Comment: Could you please give me an example? I am a beginner in development. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have multiple pages and same controller for all.

So you can identify the page Name `{!$CurrentPage.Name}`. This will give you current page name in VF page.

To get this page name in controller

Take a string variable in controller called `strCurrentPageName`

```
public String strCurrentPageName {get;set;}
```

and in Vf page use

when you click on save

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveFF}">
            <apex:param name="pageName"
                value="{!$CurrentPage.Name}"
                assignTo="{!strCurrentPageName }"/>
        </apex:commandButton>
```

Ex: [PASSING PARAMETERS WITH A COMMANDBUTTON](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/04/passing-parameters-with-a-commandbutton/)

Here value will be `{!$CurrentPage.Name}` and assignTo will be variable name.

Now when you click on save current pageName will be assign to `strCurrentPageName` variable. Do it for all the pages.

Now in save method check `strCurrentPageName` variable name and based in page name query recordType and assign the recordType.

### Another solution to get the current pageName in controller it self

If you have parameter in url

then

```
String strCurrentpgName = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl().substringBetween('apex/', '?');
```

if you don't have parameter in url

then use

```
String pageName = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl().substringAfter('apex/');
```

---

### Updates

As per your updated code.

Your controller code is correct but your page code is not correct your `apex:param` should be inside `apex:commandbutton` like this

```
 <apex:commandButton action="{!saveFF}" value="Submit" 
                                 styleClass="buttonsubmit" reRender="block" > 
     <apex:param name="p" value="{!$CurrentPage.Name}" assignTo="{!CurrentPageName}" />
 </apex:commandButton>
```

Comment: Hi Ratan, thank you very much for this detailed answer. I have added the parameter to my command button, the string to my controller, but when I use it in my if statement to get the recordtype I get an error message 'Attempt to de-reference a null object'. Do I miss something? The 2nd solution does not work in my case, I am working in Lightning and cannot pass parameter in the URL.

Comment: @ultima67 can you add your updated code in your question so I can review the code.

Comment: In the controller :  public string CurrentPageName {get;set;} public PageReference saveFF() {  RecordType rt;  if(pageName == 'HomeForm')       rt = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Home_Contents' And sObjectType = 'Fact_Finder__c'];  FF.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;   insert this.FF); return new PageReference('/' + recordId); } In the VF Page: <apex:commandButton action="{!saveFF}" value="Submit"styleClass="buttonsubmit" reRender="block" />                <apex:param name="p" value="{!$CurrentPage.Name}" assignTo="{!CurrentPageName}" /> Sorry, not the better format for code!

Comment: @ultima67 check my updates..

Comment: @ultima67 you're welcome :)